# In tkinter, why I must use 'grid' function seperately?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I was practicing how to use tkinter.

At first, I wrote a code that creates Combobox widget:

(In value 'win', I assigned tk.Tk() )

```
combobox = ttk.Combobox(win).grid(column=0, row=0)
combobox["values"] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

But it didn't worked.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".../combobox.py", line 9, in <module>
        combobox["values"] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

I guessed the order may be wrong, so I modified the code:

```
combobox = ttk.Combobox(win)
combobox["values"] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
combobox.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

Then the code worked very well...

I also tried to execute this code, and it worked well too:

```
combobox = ttk.Combobox(win)
combobox.grid(column=0, row=0)
combobox["values"] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Why the first one is wrong and the last two ones are right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example `combobox` doesn't contain `ttk.Combobox(win)` but actually the return value of `.grid(column=0, row=0)`. This means that

```
combobox["values"] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

is actually equal to

```
ttk.Combobox(win).grid(column=0, row=0)["values"] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

This is why your second example works and the first doesn't because in the second example `combobox` is set to `ttk.Combobox(win)`

Comment: Then does the error message (about 'Nonetype') means that .grid() function returns None?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

In python, when you do `x=foo().bar()`, `x` will be assigned the return value of `bar()`.

Thus, when you do `combobox = ttk.Combobox(win).grid(column=0, row=0)`, `combobox` is assigned the value from calling `grid(...)`, and calling `grid` always returns `None`.